# С# Windows Forms "Живой поиск" с использованием сторонних контролов

Tags: c#

Есть `ComboBox`. Необходимо организовать живой поиск: к примеру `ComboBox` отображающий список городов. Необходимо, чтобы выпадало меню для завершения ввода наименования, но одно НО. Вариант такого типа не годится, потому что поиск осуществляется сопоставлением первого символа вводимого значения с первым символом элемента коллекции

```
        var values = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        /////////
        cb_.AutoCompleteCustomSource = values;
        cb_.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        cb_.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

Использование стандартного ComboBox не годится. Хочется видеть реализацию как в поисковой системе Google.

Comment: Необходим частичный поиск, т.е. после ввода первого символа должен выдаваться список все городов, содержащих данную букву в своем наименовании. Какие есть у кого варианты. Спасибо.

Comment: ответ есть в оригинальном вопросе, этот, наверное, стоит удалить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ListBoxSearch
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }
/// <summary>
/// Метод,позволяющий организовать поиск в listBox.
/// Автор: Umnick
/// </summary>
/// <param name="listBox">ListBox в котором осуществляется поиск.</param>
public void Search(ListBox listBox, List<string> q)
{
    //Объявление переменных и заполнение их для поиска
    bool flag = false;
    List<int> c = new List<int>();    //Колличество совпадений
    List<string> match = new List<string>();//Список с совпадениями
    int n = 0; //Сюда запишем наибольшее кол-во совпадений
    double p = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int index = 0; //Сюда запишем индекс элемента в listbox,в котором найдено наибольшее кол-во совпадений
    List<string> s = new List<string>();//будем переписывать все items из listbox сюда
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)  //цикл,в нем заполним наши списки
    {
        s.Add(listBox.Items[i].ToString());//заполняем items
        c.Add(0);//заполняем наш счетчик нулями
    }
    //Основные циклы по работке с поиском
    for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)//Цикл,им проходимся по каждому символу в строке поиска
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < s.Count; j++)//Цикл,проходимся по каждому item в нашей коллекции,ранее мы переписали туда все items
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < s[j].Length; k++)//Цикл,посимвольно перебираем значение каждого items и ищем совпадения.
            {
                if (s[j][k] == textBox1.Text[i] || char.ToLower(s[j][k]) == textBox1.Text[i] || char.ToUpper(s[j][k]) == textBox1.Text[i])//Проверка на совпадение.Если один из символов items`а совпал с одним из символов строки поиска,увеличиваем наш счетчик
                {
                    c[j] = ++c[j];//Увеличиваем счетчик,каждый индекс которого,соответствует каждому items в listBox1.
                    count++;
                    flag = true;
                }

            }
            if (c[j] > n)//Поиск найбольшего счетчика,тоесть items,в котором было обнаружено наибольшее кол-во совпадений.
            {
                n = c[j];//...
                index = j;//Записываем в переменную,индекс,как и говорилось ранее.
            }
        }
    }
    if (flag)
    {
        listBox.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < c.Count; i++)
        {
            p += c[i];
        }
        p /= c.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Count; i++)
        {
            if (c[i] != 0)
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(s[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    if (!flag) 
    {
        listBox.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < q.Count; i++)
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(q[i]);
        }
    }
    flag = false;
   }
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Search(listBox1,items);//Вызываем наш метод,и начинаем поиск.
}
public List<string> items = new List<string>();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        items.Add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: можешь приложить фото как это выглядит на форме?

Comment: на VBA я понимаю так можно реализовывать, но на С# как-то стыдно. Может кто работал со сторонними контролами?